# TextField unable to change color Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

I don't know what happened even though I copy exactly the code from Android Developer Team official Youtube. The `textfield`  turns red BUT when I remove `color = Color.black` in `SearchBar`composable, everything works fine. Help me

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MySootheApp()
        }
    }
}


@Composable
fun SearchBar(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    TextField(
        value = "",
        onValueChange = {},
        color = Color.Black,
        leadingIcon = { Icon(Icons.Default.Search , contentDescription = null) },
        placeholder = { Text(text = "Search Here") },
        modifier = Modifier
            .heightIn(min = 56.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth(),

    )
}
```

I have tried to remove `color = Color.Black` and it works fine

Comment: can you please specify what you actually want?

Comment: I don't see a **color** field in **TextField** parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage color of `TextField` like this in jetpack compose

```
TextField(
   ...
   textStyle = TextStyle(color = Color.Blue) 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `TextField` background shows red because you wrap the `SearchBar` composable using `Surface` composable. Which take Surface color of red set on `theme.kt` file.

If you want to change background color of `TextField` .

```
TextField(
            value = "",
            onValueChange = {},
            colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(backgroundColor = Color.Blue ),
            leadingIcon = { Icon(Icons.Default.Search , contentDescription = null) },
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(56.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth(),
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the color in the M2 `TextField` you can use:

```
TextField(
    //...
    colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(textColor = Black)
 )
```

The `color` attribute **doesn't exist** in the `TextField`.